# SQL Conditionally join tables

Tags: sql

I have two tables Task and Allocated_Task.

Allocated_Task has
AT.id, Task.id(can be null), AT.allocated_date

Task has Task.id, Task.name etc

User can give either Task.id or AT.id as input

```
select AT.id, Task.Name 
from Allocated_Task, Task 
where (Task.id = :INPUT_TASK_ID or AT.id = :INPUT_AT_id)
```

Expected Output: If user gives task.id as input it should search for task.id in Allocated_Tasks and return AT.id, Task.Name if it exists or null, Task.Name if it doesn't exist in Allocated_Tasks, If user gives AT.id then it should give At.id, task.name if task.id in Allocated_Task is not null and null if task.id in Allocated_Task

Allocated Task

```
AT.id | Task.id
---------------
  1   |  10
  2   |  null
```

Task

```
Task.Id | Name
----------------
     10 | Name1
     20 | Name2
```

OUTPUT:

```
AT.ID | NAME
---------------------------------------------------
1     | Name1 (if user gives 1 as INPUT_AT_id)
2     | null (if user gives 2 as INPUT_AT_id)
1     | Name1 (if user gives 10 as INPUT_TASK_ID)
null  | Name2 (if user gives 20 as INPUT_TASK_ID)
```

**Update:** Tasks are assigned to employees(in Thousands) and an employee can be assigned n number of tasks(10s ~ 100s) and a task can be allocated to n number of employees.


If the user is filtering by Task.Id we only need the lastest Allocated_Task.ID (storing Task Allocated time). Using full outer join is taking a few minutes to execute which is not ideal in this case. Is it possible to improve query efficiency?

Answer (score 0):

It is FULL JOIN:

```
SELECT AT.id, T.Name
FROM Allocated_Task AT
FULL JOIN Task T
  ON AT.TaskId = T.Id
WHERE T.id = :INPUT_TASK_ID
  OR AT.id = :INPUT_AT_id
```

Comment: full outer join gives the desired results but it is taking so much time. Is it possible to do it without full outer join so that query can be executed quickly?

Comment: When you use filtering by id (if id is your clustered index) this should not be very cost query.